# Query fails to store php variable in database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["is_logged_in"]))
{
die("You are not logged in");
}

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
or die("Couldn't connect to Server");

$db=mysql_select_db("library")
or die("couldn't select database");

if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($id);
echo $id;
$dt=date('m/d/Y');
$dt=mysql_real_escape_string($dt);
echo $dt;

**$q1=("INSERT INTO order VALUES(DEFAULT,$id,$dt)");**
$r1=mysql_query($q1) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$q1);

**$q2=("SELECT * FROM order WHERE uid=$id");**
$r2=mysql_query($q2) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$q2);

if($r2)
{

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{   
$oid=$row['order_id'];
$items=count($_SESSION['cart']);

for($i=1;$i<$items;$i++)
{
$isbn=$_SESSION['cart'][$i];
$q3=('INSERT INTO orderinfo(order_id,isbn) VALUES($oid,$isbn)');
$r3=mysql_query($q3) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$q3);
}
}
}
}
?>
```

this code is what i am using to insert the session array with first item as the user id and the rest the product ids into the database....
the query fails everytime and asks me to refer to the manual..
i beleive there is a problem in the way i am storing php variables into the databse..
PLEASE HELP..

Comment: Unsolicited advice: die() sucks. It's a really ugly way to handle errors. I recommend using try/catch blocks instead (http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) and handling errors by printing your error messages into your site (which can still have navigation and design) rather than just stopping execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Order` is a reserved word of Mysql

Modify theses line:

```
**$q1=("INSERT INTO `order` VALUES('DEFAULT','$id','$dt')");**

**$q2=("SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE uid=$id");**
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answering...
i did what you said and it did work...but now there are further errors...but the data is now entered...
i am looking into the errors....if i can not figure them out...i post the issue in further comments..
thankyou for helping..

Comment: @user2316706 also u need to add single quotes all the inserts...`**$q1=("INSERT INTO order VALUES('DEFAULT','$id','$dt')");**`